# Predicting the variance of a future sample

Tags: prediction, prediction-interval

Suppose that I have the dataset for wealth distribution for 50 different countries. Each country's data consists of the wealth figures for 100 random individuals in that country. Some countries have high average wealth, some low; some very equal in distribution, some very unequal (thus each country has different mean and variance).

Suppose I have taken a look at 10 countries selected randomly. I then summarize the mean of the mean wealth from each country and variance. If I now take a country at random, and then close my eyes, what can I predict about the 11th country's mean and variance, and prediction interval on them, based on what I know about the 10 I have looked at?

The actual problem I am looking at is the following: We have several cost estimators, who usually provided their estimates in the form of distributions. Due to difference in individual knowledge and confidence, the estimates between them vary. If for whatever reason, all cost estimators are not available to provide the estimates, but I have a history of their estimates from previous projects, what can I do with that historical dataset to provide a quick cost estimate?